# Is there anyways to add matlab command window into windows terminal?

Tags: matlab, windows-terminal

I'm wondering is there a command line for Matlab Command Window (Maybe like .exe or something?) to make my windows terminal can open a interactive matlab command window directly. (Just like powershell, cmd, python, wsl, etc.)

I know how to adding path to windows terminal (settings.json), and know where's Matlab install path. But I don't know about the executable of matlab command window.

Very appreciate if someone has solutions can help.

[image: windows terminal]

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html)?

Comment: I mean open a new prompt can auto run matlab command window.

Comment: That’s not related to MATLAB then, I think this question is better asked on https://superuser.com/